# QuillJS pasteHTML Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, quill

I have a custom button that uses pasteHTML() in the quill toolbar. When I click the button twice, I get an error saying, "Cannot read property 'pasteHTML' of undefined."

Steps for Reproduction

1. Go to https://codepen.io/Graphettion/pen/OxezbO
2. Type text into the editor
3. Click the  button twice

Note: In codepen under the JS settings (cog wheel) when I switch JavaScript preprocessor to babel, it works. Not sure exactly why this is.

Expected behavior:
The editor should switch back to preview text view.

Actual behavior:
It gives an error saying, "Cannot read property 'pasteHTML' of undefined."

Platforms:
Windows 10, Chrome v62.0.3202.75 , FF v54.0.1, Edge v15.15063

Version:
Quill v1.3.3

```
// Code Preview
function showHtml() {
  const txtArea = document.createElement('textarea')
  txtArea.style.cssText = "width: 100%;margin: 0px;background: rgb(29, 29, 29);box-sizing: border-box;color: rgb(204, 204, 204);font-size: 15px;outline: none;padding: 20px;line-height: 24px;font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, &quot;Courier New&quot;, monospace;position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0;border: none;display:none"

  const htmlEditor = quill.addContainer('ql-custom')
  htmlEditor.appendChild(txtArea)

  const myEditor = document.querySelector('#editor')
  quill.on('text-change', (delta, oldDelta, source) => {
    const html = myEditor.children[0].innerHTML
    txtArea.value = html

    document.querySelector('.text-output').innerHTML = html
    document.getElementById('html-output').innerText = html
  })

  const customButton = document.querySelector('.ql-showHtml');
  customButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (txtArea.style.display === '') {
      const html = txtArea.value
      this.quill.pasteHTML(html)
    }
    txtArea.style.display = txtArea.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'
  })
}
```

Comment: Just remove 'this' from this.quill.pasteHtml(html) should do, because quill already declare as global const.

Answer (score 1):

in this chunk

```
customButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (txtArea.style.display === '') {
      const html = txtArea.value
      this.quill.pasteHTML(html)
    }
    txtArea.style.display = txtArea.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'
  })
```

when you try to reference `this.quill`, `this` would be referring to `customButton`

Comment: +1 jmcgriz I just figured this out on my own and went back to SO to see your comment. Ugh, dat scope chain! Thank you man! I'd vote it up but don't have enough rep.